# Как рассчитать сопротивление воздуха 3d модели?

Tags: java, c++

Допустим, ракета. Как можно рассчитать её сопротивление воздуху на определённой высоте при определённой 3d модели? Очень хороший пример того, что мне нужно, это KSP

[image: Kerbal Space Program]

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что это не относится к программированию. Тут нужен учебник физики.

Answer (score 1):

Однозначно на этот вопрос ответить нельзя, так как аэродинамика это сложная штука. Все зависит от требуемой точности, того какие модели используются и скорости. Как самый проcтой вариант, можно просто считать сопротивление зависимо от поперечного сечения, например, F=скорость^2*площадь сечения*магическое число. В том же KSP до 1.0.0, сопротивление считалось исходя из массы, плюс модификаторы подъемной силы у крыльев, после туда завезли аэродинамику получше, но она все еще относительно кривая. Как неплохой вариант, можно взять код из мода для того же KSP, [Ferram Aerospace Research](https://github.com/ferram4/Ferram-Aerospace-Research/tree/master/FerramAerospaceResearch/LEGACYferram4), там, вроде как, строится воксельная модель аппарата и по ней очень даже неплохо считаются аэродинамические силы